# Реконструирование путей после алгритма влойда

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте я столкнулся с такой проблемой что не могу придумать как востановить путь от каких нибудь произвольных вершин 
Сам алгоритм выглядит так

```
 public void AlgorithmFloida(int n, int[,] matrixA, int[,] matrixC, int[,] matrixP)
        {
            FillMatrix(matrixA, matrixC, n);
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if ((matrixC[i, k] + matrixC[k, j]) < matrixC[i, j])
                        {
                            matrixC[i, j] = matrixC[i, k] + matrixC[k, j];
                            matrixP[i, j] = k; // В матрицу P заполняю веришины 

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Вот здесь я пытаюсь в лист восстановить путь

```
 private void CalculatePath(int i,int j)
        {
            int k;
            k = matrixP[i, j];

            if (k == -1)
            {
                return;
            }
            CalculatePath(i, k);
            listOfVertrex.Add(k + 1);
            CalculatePath(k,j);
        }
```

Что я делаю не так

Comment: `алгритма влойда` нет в природе

Comment: судя по коду, вы собираете длины путей в графе. Что именно вы хотите восстановить, если у вас есть только длина пути?

Comment: я в матрице P запоминаю вершины где произошли изменения

Comment: но что эти вершины означают? Ну будет у вас для пары узлов длина пути 10 и записанная вершина 6, что это вам даст?

Comment: я, кажется, начинаю понимать ваш ход мыслей. Но тогда получается, что вам вот это `CalculatePath(k,j);` не нужно, так как `k-j` ребро уже существует, вы же `k` считали из своей матрицы.